# React-Navigation on reload page is not getting loaded with error 'Cannot GET /Home' [react-native-web with RN]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, react-navigation, react-native-web

On first load my page is loading fine when I run app or I directly put url as localhost:8080 in navigates me to initial route localhost:8080/Home but as soon as I reload page or it auto reload page can be reloaded with specific defined URL such as localhost:8080/Home or localhost:8080/Settings and fails with error Cannot GET /Home.

[image]

I am using react-native-web with RN. Following is code for navigation file:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from './src/scence/Home/home';
import Settings from './src/scence/Settings/settings';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const linking = {
  prefixes: ['https://localhost:8080'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Root: {
        path: '/',
        initialRouteName: '/',
        screens: {
          Home: '/',
          Settings: '/settings',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
const Router = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

I am new to react-native-web Don't know what I am doing wrong also I have added react-navigation in webpack.config.js

```
const compileNodeModules = [
  // Add every react-native package that needs compiling
  'react-native-gesture-handler',
  'react-native-swipe-gestures',
  'react-native-calendars',
  '@react-navigation/native',
  '@react-navigation/stack',
  'react-navigation',
].map(moduleName => path.resolve(appDirectory, `node_modules/${moduleName}`));

const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  // Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.web.js'), // Entry to your application
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'router.js'), // Change this to your main App file
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'App.js'), // Change this to your main App file
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/images'),

    ...compileNodeModules,
  ],
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      presets,
      plugins: ['react-native-web'],
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever figure out this issue?

I managed to make the development work by adding the following to webpack.config.js file. `devServer: {historyApiFallback: true}` but I still have no idea what to do with prod.